# Bootstrap 5 - Shared border around entire dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to encase the entire bootstrap dropdown in one shared border. In bootstrap's own examples here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button it has the toggle button with it's own border and the subsequent dropdown-menu in it's own border as well.
I would like to have both the toggle button and the menu share a singular border upon clicking the toggle button and dropping down the menu items.

Any way of doing this or should I use something else from bootstrap?

Encasing these elements in a parent element with it's own border does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure CSS solution**

Change the display property of `dropdown` and play around with the border properties.

```css
.dropdown {
    display:  inline-block;
}
    
.dropdown .btn {
    background:  none;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
    
.dropdown-menu {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(36px) !important;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
    
.dropdown .btn:focus,
.dropdown .btn:hover {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
    
.dropdown .btn.show {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```